# I attempted to make a function that allows my sprites to re-produce but it create an infinite amount

Tags: python, pygame

I made a class function that will allow the animals to reproduce once they have eaten enough of a group, from there it would create a new sprite on that location, and then it should lower the energy Val of that sprite, instead it does not do this and instead causes an infinite amount of sprites to be created causing the program to slow down and crash.

this is the functions I made for it to work

```
def checkEnergy(self):
        EnergyVal=self.energy
        return EnergyVal

    def reproduce(self,energy,Xpos,Ypos):
        if energy==10:
            prey = Prey(prey_image,Xpos,Ypos )
            all_sprites.add(prey)
            Rabbit_group.add(prey)
            self.energy-=4
```

here is where I implemented it:

```
if len(carrots) > 0:
        for rabbit in Rabbit_group:
            movementx, movementy = Track(rabbit.x, carrots[0].x, rabbit.y, carrots[0].y)#how the prey move
            rabbit.move(movementx, movementy)
        energyval=prey.checkEnergy()
        rabbit.reproduce(energyval,600,700)
```

full code:

```
#simulates interactions of wild life
import math
import random
import pygame,sys 
import random
import pdb
from pygame.locals  import *


#classes--------------
class Animal(pygame.sprite.Sprite):#main class
    def __init__(self, image, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x, y))
        self.Energy=10
        
    def move(self, mx, my):#moves the sprite
        self.x += mx
        self.y += my
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))#sets the image to the position

    def is_collided_with(self, sprite):#is the eat function
        return self.rect.colliderect(sprite.rect)
    
    def checkEnergy(self):
        EnergyVal=self.energy
        return EnergyVal

    def reproduce(self,energy,Xpos,Ypos):
        if energy==10:
            prey = Prey(prey_image,Xpos,Ypos )
            all_sprites.add(prey)
            Rabbit_group.add(prey)
            self.energy-=4
    
class Predator(Animal):#class for predators
    def __init__(self):
        image = pygame.image.load('Icon.png')
        self.energy=10
        super().__init__(image, 600, 700)

  
         
class Prey(Animal):
    """prey class"""
    def __init__(self, image, x, y):
        super().__init__(image, x, y)
        self.energy=10
        #self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))
        
   
        
   


class Carrot(pygame.sprite.Sprite):#food for prey class
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = 100
        self.y = 100
        self.image = pygame.image.load('carrot.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))

# Functions-----------
def Track(AgressorX,DefenderX,AgressorY,DefenderY):#finds comapres X and Y, tells sprite how to move
    if AgressorX > DefenderX:
        XMovement=-1
    elif AgressorX< DefenderX:
        XMovement=1
    else:
        XMovement=0
        
    if AgressorY > DefenderY:
        YMovement=-1
    elif AgressorY < DefenderY: 
        YMovement=1
    else:
        YMovement=0
    return XMovement, YMovement

def leavingWindow(Xpos, Ypos):#boundry, keeps sprites in the window
    if Xpos<=0:
        return True
    elif Xpos>=950:
        return True   
    if Ypos<=0:
        return True
    elif Ypos>=750:
        return True

def Boundry(Xpos, Ypos):
    if Xpos<=0:
        Xmovement=0
    elif Xpos>=950:
        Xmovement=950
    else:
        Xmovement=+0
        
    if Ypos<=0:
        ymovement=0
    elif Ypos>=750:
        ymovement=60
    else:
        ymovement=+0
        
    return Xmovement, ymovement
    
  

pygame.init()#setsup pygame
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,800))#setsup screen
clock = pygame.time.Clock()#tells program how fast to update

timmer = 1#how long program has gone on for
#setsup the classes
predator = Predator()
predator2=Predator()
#prey = Prey()
carrot = Carrot()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
prey_image = pygame.image.load('Prey.png')


carrot_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
carrot_group.add(Carrot())

Wolf_group= pygame.sprite.Group()
Wolf_group.add(Predator())

Rabbit_group= pygame.sprite.Group()


for i in range(0, 2):
    prey = Prey(prey_image, 100 * i, 700)
    all_sprites.add(prey)
    Rabbit_group.add(prey)

#setsup the classes as sprites



all_sprites.add(carrot_group)
all_sprites.add(Wolf_group)
all_sprites.add(Rabbit_group)

#start of program
running=True
while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            running=False

    carrots = carrot_group.sprites()
    preys = Rabbit_group.sprites()
    predators = Wolf_group.sprites()

    if len(preys) > 0:
        for wolf in Wolf_group:
            movementx, movementy = Track(wolf.x, preys[0].x, wolf.y, preys[0].y)#how the predators move
            wolf.move(0,1)#movementx, #movementy)

            Leaving=leavingWindow(wolf.x,wolf.y)#keeps sprites in window
            if Leaving == True:
                movementx,movementy=Boundry(wolf.x,wolf.y)
                wolf.x=movementx
                wolf.y=movementy
    
    if len(carrots) > 0:
        for rabbit in Rabbit_group:
            movementx, movementy = Track(rabbit.x, carrots[0].x, rabbit.y, carrots[0].y)#how the prey move
            rabbit.move(movementx, movementy)
        energyval=prey.checkEnergy()
        rabbit.reproduce(energyval,600,700)

    screen.fill((0,128,0))#background
    all_sprites.draw(screen)#makes the sprites
    pygame.display.update()#updates screen
    timmer=timmer+1

    for carrot in carrots:#removes the carrots if they contact a rabbit
        for rabbit in Rabbit_group:
            if rabbit.is_collided_with(carrot):
                print('works')
                carrot.kill()

    for wolf in Wolf_group:
        for rabbit in Rabbit_group:
            if rabbit.is_collided_with(wolf):
                print("works 2")
                rabbit.kill()
    
    
pygame.quit()
exit()
```

MRE Here:

```
import pygame,sys 
import random
import pdb
from pygame.locals  import *

class Animal(pygame.sprite.Sprite):#main class
    def __init__(self, image, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x, y))
        self.Energy=10
        
    def move(self, mx, my):#moves the sprite
        self.x += mx
        self.y += my
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))#sets the image to the position

    
    def checkEnergy(self):
        EnergyVal=self.energy
        return EnergyVal

    def reproduce(self,energy,Xpos,Ypos):
        if energy==10:
            prey = Prey(prey_image,Xpos,Ypos )
            all_sprites.add(prey)
            Rabbit_group.add(prey)
            self.energy-=4
         
class Prey(Animal):
    """prey class"""
    def __init__(self, image, x, y):
        super().__init__(image, x, y)
        self.energy=10
        #self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))

pygame.init()#setsup pygame
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,800))#setsup screen
clock = pygame.time.Clock()#tells program how fast to update

timmer = 1#how long program has gone on for

prey_image = pygame.image.load('Prey.png')

Rabbit_group= pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites=pygame.sprite.Group()

for i in range(0, 2):
    prey = Prey(prey_image, 100 * i, 700)
    all_sprites.add(prey)
    Rabbit_group.add(prey)

#setsup the classes as sprites

all_sprites.add(Rabbit_group)

#start of program
running=True
while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            running=False
            
    preys = Rabbit_group.sprites()
    
    for rabbit in Rabbit_group:     
        rabbit.move(0, -1)
    energyval=prey.checkEnergy()
    rabbit.reproduce(energyval,600,700)

    screen.fill((0,128,0))#background
    all_sprites.draw(screen)#makes the sprites
    pygame.display.update()#updates screen
    timmer=timmer+1

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

I'm pretty sure the issue is `self.energy-=4` I don't think its working properly but I am unsure on how to fix it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with an emphasis on *minimal*.

Comment: I don't understand, there's no infinite reproduction when I ran your code, it simply stops when the moving sprite hits a carrot..

Comment: would me recording it from my side be helpful (as I am making a MRE its just taking a bit)

Comment: @Ann when you said the reproduction stopped does that mean it caused a huge line of them to head towards the carrot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I made a class function that will allow the animals to reproduce once they have eaten enough of a group [...]

You do the evaluation at the wrong place.

```py
    if len(carrots) > 0:
        for rabbit in Rabbit_group:
            movementx, movementy = Track(rabbit.x, carrots[0].x, rabbit.y, carrots[0].y)#how the prey move
            rabbit.move(movementx, movementy)
        # energyval=prey.checkEnergy()        <--- DELETE
        # rabbit.reproduce(energyval,600,700) <--- DELETE
```

Increment the energy when the rabbit eats a carrot. And reproduce the rabbit if the energy reaches the threshold:

```py
class Animal(pygame.sprite.Sprite):#main class
    # [...]

    def reproduce(self):
        if self.energy >= 10:
            prey = Prey(self.image, self.x, self.y)
            all_sprites.add(prey)
            Rabbit_group.add(prey)
            self.energy -= 4
```

```py
while running:
    # [...]

    for carrot in carrots:#removes the carrots if they contact a rabbit
        for rabbit in Rabbit_group:
            if rabbit.is_collided_with(carrot):
                print('works')
                carrot.kill()

                rabbit.energy += 1
                rabbit.reproduce()
```